# Emacs TRAMP not activated with Dired

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp, dired

I've been using TRAMP for a few days now.  It works very well for the most part.  I can load a remote shell using `M-x shell`, and `ido-mode` with `find-file` works very well remotely as well, which was surprising to me.

However, I'm having trouble with `dired-do-shell-command`.  When I select a remote file using `dired`, then use `!` to invoke `dired-do-shell-command`, it attempts to do this locally.  Why does it do that if `find-file` and `dired` itself use TRAMP transparently?

I'm confused about how TRAMP really ties into the rest of Emacs.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour on my system. Please try to do the same test with a standard Emacs configuration (`emacs -q`) and see if this problem still happens...

Comment: @Francesco unfortunately it still happens.  When I attempt to invoke p4 (Perforce), it says "/bin/sh: p4: command not found"

Comment: try to invoke something like `hostname`, to really see where the command is being executed. There are so many ways perforce could fail (like environment problems), that you might be mistaken about the origin of the problem.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce. What Emacs version are you using?